# InputMismatchException for 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

Check the comments below.

I was using...

```
Scanner input = new Scanner("rates.txt");
```

Should be using...

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("rates.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it as below:
 In your code

```
       Scanner input = new Scanner("rates.txt");
```

should be:

```
       Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("rates.txt"));
```

Keep it inside **try-catch** or add **throws Exception** in main method.

Also give the full path of file if it does not found the file.

Comment: I thought doing this would overwrite my current file, so I never did it... and now it's working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use reader instead of scanner.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("rates.txt"));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // parse line here . . .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a String to the Scanner constructor, you're telling it that the input will come from the String itself. You should use a File object or something equivalent. This is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = null;

        try
        {
            input = new Scanner(new File("rates.txt"));

        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
           ioe.printStackTrace();

        }

        int numRows    = 7;
        int numColumns = 7;

        Double[][] ratesArray = new Double[numRows][numColumns];

        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < ratesArray.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < ratesArray[i].length; j++)
                {
                    ratesArray[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print(ratesArray[i][j] + "\t");

                } // for j

                System.out.print("\n");

            } // for i

        } // while

        input.close();

    } // main()

} // class TestFile
```